# How to post file to local file by curl

Tags: php, phpunit

```
 public function curl($source = null, $type = 'get', $fields = array())
    {
        $result = '';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

        if (strtolower($type) === 'post') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

            if (count($fields) !== 0) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
            }
        }

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($result === false) {
            $result = curl_error($ch);
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```

This is my curl function, I would like to do `PHPUnit` test to check some other upload file function, therefore I need to simulate form post method with file in `PHPUnit`, the problem is, `curl` need to give domain name, of course I can get domain by `$_SERVER` method, but in command line it won't work, how will you do unitest to test a file upload behavior.